# Getting an error "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied."

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    Scaffold(topBar = { AppBar() } ) {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(it)) {
            Column() {
                ProfileCard()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun AppBar(){
    TopAppBar(
        title = { Text(text = "Hi")}
    ) {}
}
```

I'm getting 2 error

- [@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPODS.png)
- [None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpIPt.png)

I'm trying to add a TopAppBar but if i give a composable for title or navigationIcon I get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
@Composable
fun AppBar(){

 TopAppBar( title = { Text("Hi")},)
}
```